# Compile from source and ensure updatability

Tags: maintenance, automatic-maintenance

I would like to setup a new server with the following packages

- Ngnix with SPDY and PageSpeed extension
- PHP-FPM with Phalcon extension
- MySQL with Sphinx extension
- Sphinx

In order to have the most recent versions and for the case of SPDY and PageSpeed for Nginx and Sphinx for MySQL I need to compile the applications from source.

Now appears the following question. Is it possible to make it updatable?
How do you keep your self-compiled software updated?

Comment: Aren't the 2 mutually exclusive, unless you set up a build farm... then how do you decide when it's time to build, nightly, weekly, when the next release fork is made?

Comment: I will build it manually. It's just not clear for me, how to update the already installed and running software and how to organize it.

Comment: You do a git pull the build it.